# Content decimal

Tags: gatsby, netlify, contentful, snipcart

In a Gatsby project, combined with a Contentful Space, I have a decimal field for setting a product price (see image below)

You see the price with a comma (Dutch locale f.i.), while I need it with a decimal point, to process the decimal number further. What should I do to accept the (en-US) decimal point?

[image: Contentful]

@Gordon Burgett: This is what I entered on the command line, and the result:
[curl Contentful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fodwL.jpg) {follow the link; the picture is not showing}

@GordonBurgett: Well, I see the price with a decimal point.
But now the question lies with Snipcart; I test my app, deployed to Netlify. And Snipcart verifies the price, and then it goes wrong. For some reason, it does not recognize the price.

[image: GraphiQL]

Comment: would you please post what this entry looks like when you access it via the API? `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID/entries/{the entry id}?locale=*`

Comment: @GordonBurgett: "The resource could not be found"

Comment: That means it's not published.  When you do `gatsby develop`, can you query the price in the graphIQL editor?  What is the result?